# Maze Drawing (better performance) libgdx

Tags: java, android, performance, opengl-es, libgdx

In my game, I'm using the ShapeRenderer class to draw a maze. Basically, I'm using the rectangle function (in the ShapeRenderer class) to draw small black lines. In the past, I had no problem debugging the game performance-wise (fps = 60). But lately, I've been having some performance issues. To make it short, I took out every sprites and actors I've drawn in the game and decided to draw the maze ONLY. Everytime I debug my game through the Desktop Launcher,  the fps performance lowers by half (basically around 33, 34 fps). Yet, when i run it, it goes up to 60 fps.

I believe that it's a clear indication that the ShapeRenderer class wouldn't be the best choice for me to draw the maze performance-wise. I've tried with a spritebatch with texture png image (rectangle) and that didn't change a thing. I was wondering if there was a better choice to draw the maze and still maintain an fps performance to 60 (in debug mode) or is it just normal that debugging the game would lower my fps performance by half?

P.S: This is my code which is inside the render method to draw the maze:

```
for(int x = 0; x < rows; x++){
     for(int y = 0; y < columns; y++){

         if(this.grid[x][y].north.hasWall){ //NORTH BORDER LINE
             shapeRenderer.rect(22+((GENERIC_WIDTH_HEIGHT_MAZE+10)*x), 450-((GENERIC_WIDTH_HEIGHT_MAZE+10)*y), GENERIC_WIDTH_HEIGHT_MAZE+10, 0, color1, color2, color3, color4); 
         }
         if(this.grid[x][y].west.hasWall){ //WEST BORDER LINE
              shapeRenderer.rect(22+((GENERIC_WIDTH_HEIGHT_MAZE+10)*x), 450-((GENERIC_WIDTH_HEIGHT_MAZE+10)*y), 0, -GENERIC_WIDTH_HEIGHT_MAZE-10, color1, color2, color3, color4);
         }
         if(this.grid[x][y].east.hasWall){ //EAST BORDER LINE
                  shapeRenderer.rect(22+((GENERIC_WIDTH_HEIGHT_MAZE+10)*(x+1)), 450-((GENERIC_WIDTH_HEIGHT_MAZE+10)*y), 0, -GENERIC_WIDTH_HEIGHT_MAZE-10, color1, color2, color3, color4);

         }
         if(this.grid[x][y].south.hasWall){ //SOUTH BORDER LINE
              shapeRenderer.rect(22+((GENERIC_WIDTH_HEIGHT_MAZE+10)*x), 450-((GENERIC_WIDTH_HEIGHT_MAZE+10)*(y+1)), GENERIC_WIDTH_HEIGHT_MAZE+10, 0, color1, color2, color3, color4);
         }
     }
 }
```

Any insights would be appreciated. are the following values:

```
GENERIC_WIDTH_HEIGHT_MAZE = 26 (Integer)
rows = 9
columns = 12
color1 = color2 = color3 = color4 = Color.BLACK
```

Comment: Provide more context, e.g. the values of rows, height, generic_width_height_maze and other information that might be relevant.

Comment: Anybody has any clue?

Comment: Provide complete render() method please

Comment: Actually, this is all there is in the render() method. Nothing else but that.

Comment: You forgot to clear the backbuffer, this causes the gpu to reconstruct the backbuffer each time. You should add something like Gdx.gl.glClear(...). Also, you are never calling shapeRenderer.begin / end and are never setting the projection matrix. So it is highly unlikely that this displays anything at all.

Comment: @Xoppa: I should've added more information. (I was mentally tired). I actually have the following code in my render() method:  Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f); Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT); //Clears the screen. Then inside the draw() method, I setup my camera like this:   if(camera == null){  camera = new OrthographicCamera(VIEWPORT_WIDTH, VIEWPORT_HEIGHT);
camera.position.set(camera.viewportWidth / 2, camera.viewportHeight / 2, 0f);  update();}; afterwards I do have shapeRenderer.begin() and then I draw the maze. after which the shapeRenderer.end() is being called.

Comment: @Xoppa: even after setting the projection matrix before the shapeRenderer.begin(), it is still slow. I've finally change the shapeRenderer by using small texture .png image to draw the lines of the maze and the fps performance want to 60. Still I'm baffled as to why it would give me some performance issues after months of debugging.

Comment: @C.O.D.E its already mentioned that shape renderer for a debugging only and has low performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, in the end, I made a TextureAtlas containing the walls drawn (small png pics) and called two of them  (one horizontal and on vertical) to draw the maze and got rid of ShapeRenderer. Like Deniz Yılmaz mentionned, ShapeRendereris only used for debugging which is probably why the performance slows down inside the for loop. I also a couple of other performance optimization on other parts of my code. Now the performance is at 60 fps all the time. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 2):

If when you run it the rendering speed is good enough then I would not worry about the performance when debugging.

But in general this looks like something you can optimize greatly:

1. Since it is a maze you can significantly reduce the number of draw calls by generating "blobs". You can join the walls and even use triangle stripes to draw the whole chunks.
2. Are you using face culling to reduce a number of fragments? (you should)
3. You most likely don't need to draw all of the walls anyway. Create a system to find only the walls that are not behind other walls (should be easy since it looks like a normal 2d grid).
4. Reduce redundant calls: I assume you keep setting things like color for every rect you draw. Try to do that only when it needs changing.
5. The maze is most likely static or changes rarely. Generate a GPU buffer on load time with all the vertices and then keep reusing that buffer to reduce the traffic to the GPU.

Again these are just a few pointers where you may optimize but I would try to optimize it as late as possible and only if needed. Being too slow on debug is usually not a good reason to start optimizing.

Since there can be very many reasons why the debug is slow you might want to have a system to check what is your actual drawing FPS at the moment. You may test this by drawing your scene to a FBO of the same size as your screen and try to just keep drawing your scene in a for (or) while loop and measure FPS. This gives you the rough estimation as to how close to your limit you are.

Comment: @ Matic Oblak: #2) what will face culling do? From what I've read, it's only used for 3d shapes. I'm just showing a 2d maze. 5) How do you generate a GPU buffer? do you have link or tutorial I could follow do that? 1) How would I be able to do that?